# Jsr223 assertion failing for json response in jmeter

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I am getting json response in a request like
Response=

```
[
  {
   "id":"1",
   "name":"Elfred",
   "city":"mexico",
    "@type":"author"
  },
  {
   "id":"2",
    "name":"michael",
    "city":"San Fransico",
    "@type":"Editor"}
]
```

I aM USING jsr223 Assertion I wanted to check my json Response contains keys :
groovy Code:

```
    import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
    import java.util.*;
    def failureMessage = "";
    def jsonResponse = null;
    JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper ();
jsonResponse = JSON.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
if (!jsonResponse.keySet().containsAll("id","name","city","@type")) {
    
          failureMessage += "The json config element has wrong structure.\n\n";
}
```

I am getting Exception as

```
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.keySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: toSet(), toSet(), set(int, java.lang.Object), set(int, java.lang.Object), get(int), get(int)
```

What am i missing ??

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) as the response, if you want to check each and every JSON Object which is inside the array so you need to amend your code like:

```
def jsonResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def failureMessage = ""

jsonResponse.each { entry ->
    if (!entry.keySet().containsAll('id', 'name', 'city', '@type')) {
        failureMessage += 'The json config element has wrong structure.\n\n'
    }
}
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

In general it's better to use a library like [JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema) rather than parsing the JSON manually, presumably you either should have a [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) or it's possible to generate one.